# Bootstrap - Dropdown menu disappears too quickly on unhover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar and I have changed it so that the dropdown menu shows whenever one **hovers** over the menu items (instead of whenever one clicks). This works, but there is something off: The dropdown disappears very quickly and irregularly, it's not so easy to just hover and then click on something. I am not sure how to describe this but I think you will see what I mean, everything just seems a little bit too "quick".

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/r3sjgq2c/

**Edit: I am talking about the menu in the large viewport, not about the small viewport!**

Here is the code:

```
<div class="header container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="brand col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 hidden-xs-down">
      <svg class="brand_logo"><use xlink:href="#brand_logo" /></svg>
    </div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Welcome<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown_angebot" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Pricing
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_angebot">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="softwareentwicklung.php">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="qualitaetssicherung.php">Another action</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com">
          Our Company
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" >
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="geschichte.php">History</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="karriere.php">Career</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="klienten.php">Clients</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="anfahrt.php">Get here<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="kontakt.php">Contact<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-toggler{
  z-index: 999999 !important;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;

  .navbar-toggler {
        margin-top: 20px !important;
  }

  .navbar {
    height: 50px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    background-color: yellow !important;

    .navbar-nav {
        display: table !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        list-style: none !important;

        .nav-link {
          padding: 0 !important;
        }

        li {
        display: table-cell !important;
        text-align: center !important;

          a {
            display: block !important;
            text-align: center !important;
          }

          &:first-child a {
              text-align: left !important;
          }
          &:last-child a {
              text-align: right !important;
          }



          &:hover .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-item:hover .dropdown-menu {
              display: block !important;
          }
          .dropdown-menu {
            // margin-top: 10px;
            left: 50% !important;
            transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
          }

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to appear and disappear with a transition, or are you just having trouble clicking on the menu on account of it disappearing too fast? cause I've tried and I don't have trouble clicking the dropdown

Comment: The latter. if you are just a little bit too slow or try to move down vertically a little bit more slowly, then the dropdown just disappears too quickly.

Comment: see my edit. I am talking about the large viewport, not about the hamburger dropdown thing!

Comment: If you mean the Pricing / Our Company dropdowns, I don't see how it is difficult to click on the dropdown. It only disappears when you move the mouse out of an area that includes the dropdown. Give a margin to the dropdown-menu so that the hovering area includes a bit more space. also some padding to the nav-item dropdown so that it's a bigger hovering area to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I do mean that. I have done as you suggested but it does not do much, it seems. it just moves things down a little bit, but the problem remains.

Comment: I just want to make it impossible for the user to hover over the menu item, scroll down and then have the dropdown menu disappear while he/she is doing that.

Comment: But then you would have to use dropdown mouseout event to close the dropdown and that would mean that if the user hovers without intention of using it, it would stay open awkwardly. I don't think it's bad right now. With some padding and margin you can give some more room to avoid involuntarily leaving the hover area, but more than that I think it's just unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

add this in your javascript file. also add 
include this jquery to top off your all js file

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js



$(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
            function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeIn("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
            },
            function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeOut("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
            });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. is there not a easier solution though, that does not require ad hoc javascript modifications? it also seems to change the css positioning of the dropdown.